# How to enable texture acceleration in a VM running XP?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, directx

In my Windows 8 PC, I'm running a VM with Windows XP vía VirtualBox. I'm trying to play a game that uses DirectX 8.1. The `dxdiag` tool says DirectX 9.0c is installed, so there's no problem with the version. Under the Display/Screen tab, I have:

- DirectDraw acceleration (enabled)
- Direct3D acceleration (enabled)
- Texture acceleration (not available)

I used to have *Direct3D acceleration (not available)* and the game couldn't run. I solved that by enabling the *3D acceleration* at my VM settings. Now the game runs, but when it's time to play I just see a black screen.

Using the *dxdiag* tool and testing Direct3D fails, this is the error log:

```
Test results Direct3D 7: Failure at step 8 (Creating 3D Device): HRESULT = 0x8007000e (Out of memory) 
Test results Direct3D 8: Failure at step 32 (User check processing Direct3D): HRESULT = 0x00000000 (error code) 
Test results Direct3D 9: Failure at step 32 (User check processing Direct3D): HRESULT = 0x00000000 (error code)
```

I think the problem is there or I need to enable the texture acceleration. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the "Guest Additions" on that VM windows you can get 3D, is a prerequisite for use that function, but not wait miracles. Here is how you can install it:

In the "Devices" menu in the virtual machine's menu bar, VirtualBox has a handy menu item named "Insert Guest Additions CD image", which mounts the Guest Additions ISO file inside your virtual machine. A Windows guest should then automatically start the Guest Additions installer, which installs the Guest Additions into your Windows guest.

More info on :

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already did that. Direct3D is active now, but it's not working (the dxdiag test fails).

Comment: Bad luck then. Usually works better with OpenGl. The 3d function for virtualbox is now a work in progress.

Answer (score -1):

As XP spins up on the VirtualBox press F8 - to enter the safe mode with networking option, run the guest additions: in that mode; ticking Direct3D option on the way through. You might find this to be enough depending on which game you're talking about. I realise this thread is virtually (see how I did that!) four years old, however you can do an not overly complicated XP within circa 8GB as opposed to > 10GB for Windows 7 and lots more for Windows 10. This relatively small amount of space can be very useful under certain circumstances!